# Cant draw hills on terrain in Unity 5.3.2

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

Im new to unity so please ignore my mistakes :p

My problem is that, I placed a terrain in my scene, made the environment as i wanted, and now i want to make some changes in it, like draw some more hills, put grass and trees,

But now when I select "Raise/ Lower" tool from the inspector to draw hills on my terrain....nothing happens....However when I place a new terrain everything works fine :( I made that environment last day, now when I tried to make changes by doing the same as I did yesterday, but its not working....:/ Am i doing something wrong? please tell me

Comment: either this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/35897/painting-terrain-problem.html or another glitch or you messed up something somehow, but it's definitely not a "supported behaviour" (i.e. you should be able to edit the terrain)

Comment: I have gone through that thread before posting this problem but it didn't helped me. A few guys there are able to put some textures, the first or default ones but I cant do that even...the only thing I could do is change the position of the terrain..

Comment: hard to tell what's going on with issues of the kind. try to save a prefab of it, create a brand new project, import the prefab and edit. if it works, probably some editor issue/bug. if not, there's a setting went silly on the terrain. either way it's a good idea to report to unity